# How to start developing plugin for Apple's multimedia products , such as iMovie, iLife etc?

Tags: plugins, chromakey, imovie

Here is one sample product [iMovie plug-in for Chroma Key](http://www.kudlian.net/products/essential/)

I want to get some advice or suggest from people who had real experience on apple product plugin development.

Comment: seems like that there is no sdk for imovie plugin development now.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2211026&tstart=0&messageID=10471244#10471244